# I tried converting class-based component to a functional component but it isn't quite working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component, react-portal

I just want to know if it is possible to convert a class component into a functional component regarding the context below. The main things I do not understand/know:

In the context below the RCC has a static method create(), and an unbound method `show()`, how can I do the same in a RFC? I can call the show function in any other Components like you would call a normal function. For example in a `fetch(url).then(data=>data.payload).catch(err=>settingsService.show())`

the files:

SettingsDialog\Settings.jsx,
SettingsDialog\settingsService.jsx

Settings.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component, forwardRef } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import axios from "axios";

const url  = `http://localhost:8081/api/role`; 


let resolve;

class Settings extends Component {

static create() {
    const containerElement = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(containerElement);
    return render(<Settings/>, containerElement);
  }


 constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     isOpen: false,
     checked: false,
     data: []
   };

    this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    this.handleConfirm = this.handleConfirm.bind(this);
    this.handleSelectionProps = this.handleSelectionProps.bind(this);
 }


 handleCancel() {
    this.setState({isOpen: false});
    resolve(false);
  }

  handleConfirm() {
    this.setState({isOpen: false});
    resolve(true);
  }

  handleSelectionProps(rowData){
    return {
      disabled:
      this.state.checked && this.state.checked.length >= 2 && !rowData.tableData.checked
          ? true
          : false
    };
  };

  show(title,content) {
    this.setState({isOpen: true});
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
      this.setState({data:response.data.payload});
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {console.error(error);this.setState({data:[]})});
    return new Promise((res) => {
      resolve = res;
    });
  }


 render() {


   const { isOpen } = this.state;
   return(
    <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={this.handleCancel} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
      <DialogContent>
       <p>Dialog content</p>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={this.handleConfirm}color="primary" variant="contained">
            OK
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    )
    }
} export default Settings;
```

settingsService.jsx code :

```
import Settings from './Settings';
export default Settings.create();
```

Whenever I call settingsService.show() the component pops up.  I want to know if is possible to do the same with a functional component.

Comment: Yes, this certainly looks like it could be converted. I haven't come across much that couldn't be converted. Did you try it yet?

Comment: Yes i did, but unfortunately i'm quite new with react and react functional components and hooks.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to something like "I tried converting class-based component to a functional component but it isn't quite working" and provide your attempt and as many relevant details as possible.

Comment: Wait... where do you call `settingsService.show()`? I guess this is a tangential question as the *actual* component can be converted, but this static function call looks like a react anti-pattern.

Comment: i can call the show function in any other Components like you would call a normal function. For example in a fetch(url).then(data=>data.payload).catch(err=>settingsService.show())